# Flask returns 'Method not allowed' when submitting form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am closely following the [very brief tutorial from Flask-wtf here](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html). I have an issue where after I submit my name in my *submit* page form, it gives a "**405 Method Not Allowed**" message instead of directing me to the success page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from forms import MyForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecretKey'


@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)


@app.route('/success')
def success():
    return "Well done for entering your name!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My form is here:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

My submit.html code is shown below (just like in the tutorial):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Password page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="/">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The `if form.validate_on_submit()` condition does not return True so the contents of the loop do not execute. I added a simple print statement in it which didn't execute.

Comment: maybe `action="/"` needs to be changed to `action="/submit"`

Comment: Sure. `@app.route('/success')` doesn't specify the access methods, so it'll default to just `GET`. You need `@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])`

Comment: @roganjosh I still get the same error after adding this.

Comment: Hmm, ok. What route is throwing the error (look into the console to see where the request went)? Something seems awry

Comment: @roganjosh see my EDIT. for some reason the validate_on_submit doesn't seem to be returning True and thus doesn't enter the loop

Comment: Try changing `action="/"` to `action="{{ url_for('submit') }}"`. I'm missing something basic here, sorry

Comment: The form validation will fail on first landing on the page, so you'll want to have `if request.method == 'POST':` before trying form validation, but I don't think that explains the issue

Comment: @roganjosh Changing the action tag worked! Can you post this as a separate answer so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Umair apologies your suggestion worked and you were the first to comment it. I somehow missed your comment.

Comment: Shouldn't action point to the correct endpoint instead of `/` ?

Comment: Ack, I think there might be a dupe that you'd be better accepting than me taking a stab at an answer here. I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be lying if I pretended to know exactly how all relative paths are resolved. However, you can fix this by changing:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
```

to:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('submit') }}">
```

It's one of those things that it really does make sense to pass the issue off to the library to figure out. Use [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) which also works in Jinja2 when rendering the template.

Comment: @piccolo it would, _in this case_. Wait till you have blueprints etc. Then it's a bit much. Just point to the view name and avoid the stress :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not mentioning that the method `success` should handle POST requests.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from forms import MyForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecretKey'


@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)


@app.route('/success')
def success():
    return "Well done for entering your name!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

with

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from forms import MyForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecretKey'


@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)

# This is the change I made.
@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])
def success():
    return "Well done for entering your name!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi Sanil, I still get the same error after adding the POST method to success.

Comment: @Sanil why would you think this was the problem? The form handling code is in `submit`, which already accepts POST, not `success`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it looks like the `if form.validate_on_submit()` does not return True and so it can't go to the `success` page. What are your thoughts?